# Unable to ping DNS server from Guest OS using IPv6

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, dns, ipv6, ping

I am able to ping DNS server(2001:4860:4860::8888) from my host machine(Windows) using IPv6, but
I am unable to ping DNS server(2001:4860:4860::8888) from my virtual machine(Windows) using IPv6.

The host machine has two network adapters(Wi-Fi & VMnet8).
The virtual machine has one adapter Ethernet0.

What are the configurations that need to be done in both Host and VM to ping DNS server successfully from VM?

When I try to ping from VM, VM is sending neighbor solicitation instead echo-request. Can you please tell why echo-request is not sending?

Answer (score 1):

`When I try to ping from VM, VM is sending neighbor solicitation instead echo-request. Can you please tell why echo-request is not sending.`

IPv6 does not use arp to find the MAC address of neighbours on the same lan. Instead it makes the multicast call neighbour solicitation which should be for a connected router, given that the address is for Google. This is within the `fe02::/32` subnet. When that succedes, then it will send the echo request.

If you are seeing that call from the host, then there are at least 4 possibilites:

1. The guest has firewall rules in place
2. The guest does not have a global IPv6 address, only a local one
3. The guest has no IPv6 route setup and therefore either does not know what the correct route is or it is sending it out of the wrong interface
4. The guest is unable to determine what the address is of the local exit router.

Comment: I have two machines, let's say A & B. A has two n/w adapters A1 & A2. B has one n/w adapter B1. A1 is connected to access point(Mobile's hotspot). A2 is connected to B1. I can ping DNS server from A.  but I am unable to ping from B. A1 has IPv6 "2409:4070:4010:c667:b879:69a8:eb5d:5bbf". What are the IP's I should use for A2 and B1.

Comment: As per my understanding, Solicitation and Advertisement packets are exchanged with in LAN. If my understanding is correct. then If the given IPv6 address is with in LAN, then receiver will reply with neighbour advertise packet. What if the given address is from public domain like DNS server IP. then there won't be any response right..!, then what the sender will do?